# Editing file from Sublime Text 2 from Command Line when SSH'd into a Vagrant Virtual Box (Linux Ubuntu Machine)

Tags: postgresql, sublimetext2, vagrant

I'm developing Ruby on Rails application on a Windows 7 machine but running it on a Linux Ubuntu Virtual Box using Vagrant.  I need to access the Postgres pg_hba.conf file and edit it using Sublime Text 2.  It's in the /Vagrant/etc path so I have to access from command line.  Please let me know - I appreciate the help.

Comment: So you know the location of the file you want to edit in a guest system (Ubuntu) and it is available for your host system (W7) via `/Vagrant/etc/` path (Oracle Virtual Box shared folder) ? So I see no problems here - just launch your favourite editor (that seems to be Sublime Text 2) and do the job !

Comment: actually - I'm not sure where the '/Vagrant/etc/' path is on my host system.  I have one shared folder which is where I keep my Rails app but there is no Vagrant folder there.  Can you please advise?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do you really need to edit it with Sublime Text 2?

If you have access to it at the command line, then why not just use an editor in the Ubuntu environment?  You should have [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/) available.

Comment: good point - i didn't need sublime text, i just didn't know any better at the time. thank you